# activiating plantuml from asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoctor, plantuml

I want to activate plantuml from asciidoctor

From asciidctor I learned:

anchor:id[optional xreflabel]

is equal to

[[id,optional xreflabel]]

but where is the anchor?

linux mint asciidoctor 1.5.6 GraphViz installed

preview in IntelliJ with asciidoctor plugin does not work

plantuml::images/diagramm.puml[] // works

[plantuml,images/diagramm.puml] // works not

how to write the correct embedding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking two distinct questions.

First, the `anchor:id[optional xref label]` syntax is equivalent to `[[id, optional xref label]]`. These provide a target location within a document that cross-reference links can point to, but anchors are not themselves visible. The optional label is used to label links that point to the anchors.

For example, when this Asciidoctor document is converted to HTML:

```
= Document

First: anchor:alice[Alice]

Second: [[bob, Bob]]

Link to <<alice>>.

Link to <<bob>>.
```

the HTML looks like:

```html
...
<div id="header">
<h1>Document</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div class="paragraph">
<p>First: <a id="alice"></a></p>
</div>
<div class="paragraph">
<p>Second: <a id="bob"></a></p>
</div>
<div class="paragraph">
<p>Link to <a href="#alice">Alice</a>.</p>
</div>
<div class="paragraph">
<p>Link to <a href="#bob">Bob</a>.</p>
</div>
</div>
...
```

If your document includes an anchor but never links to it, the anchor markup is omitted from the output.

For your second question, you already answered it. When the `asciidoctor-plantuml` extension is installed, it provides support for the `plantuml:` macro. Whenever you include `plantuml::path/to/plantuml/diagram.puml[]` in your document, the extension renders the specified PlantUML diagram file and emits the resulting image where the macro would have appeared in the output.

Using `[plantuml,images/diagramm.puml]` would only specify an anchor with the id `plantuml`, and any cross-reference links that point to it would be literally labelled `images/diagramm.puml`.

Comment: Is it possible to give the id another definition as the path to the puml-file?

Comment: hmmm I dont added plantuml extenstion , I added asciidoctor-diagram

Comment: See [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037280/strange-counting-in-asciidoctor) also

Comment: Yes, you can specify an id for any block. Add `[[id]]` on the line immediately preceding the block that should receive the id.

Comment: `asciidoctor-diagram` can invoke PlantUML for rendering, but does not itself install PlantUML.

Answer (score 0):

The "asciidoc" intellij extension can render plantuml,
by adding the kroki url (`https://world-tsp-ci-assurance.is.echonet/kroki/`)
into the following form:

> /File/settings/Languages&Frameworks/AsciiDoc/Use kroki to render
> diagram instead of Asciidoctor Diagram/url of custom kroki instance

this will activate all the kroki supported languages: not only plantuml:

```
actdiag 
blockdiag   
bpmn    
bytefield   
c4plantuml  
ditaa   
erd 
excalidraw  
graphviz    
mermaid 
nomnoml 
nwdiag  
packetdiag  
plantuml    
rackdiag    
seqdiag 
svgbob  
umlet   
vega    
vegalite    
wavedrom
```