# strange counting in Asciidoctor?

Tags: asciidoctor

I want to count my figures automatically

I use Asciidcotor 1.5.6

```
:desc-image-fr: FR Text
[id="image-fr",reftext="{figure-caption} {counter:figures}"]
.{desc-image-fr}
image::fr.png[align="center"]

:desc-image-ab: AB Text
.{desc-image-ab}
[plantuml,id="image-ab",format="png",title="{desc-image-ab}" reftext="{figure-caption} {counter:figures}",align="center"]
----
() "FR"          as GS
() "AB"          as AB
----
look in <<image-ab>> and <<image-fr>>
```

This is the result:

...here is the image...

Figure 3. FR Text

...here is rendered png of plantuml...

Figure 5. AB Text

look in Figure 4 and Figure 3

I am surprised about the "Figure 5"... Why 5 and not 4?

---

EDIT: added info from pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
                    <version>9.1.12.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0-alpha.16</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctorj-diagram</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.18</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

Why the extension is not activated?

Comment: "...here is the image..." I don't think that's true.

Comment: I don't have PlantUML installed, but I do have Mermaid, so I adjusted the `[plantuml ...]` block with:

```
[mermaid,id="image-ab",title="{desc-image-ab}" reftext="{figure-caption} {counter:figures}",align="center"]
```
I get the expected output.

Can you show us how you are invoking asciidoctor?

Comment: Searching for the problem, I learned, the asciidoctor-diagramm chain in maven is not working at all (sneftels guess). I only see the images in the IntelliJ preview (using plugins).

Comment: So: [plantuml... triggers one cound and ---- seems to trigger another count in the plugins

Comment: But, I will try  mermaid, Thank you

Comment: I exchanged plantuml with mermaid. It has the same effect: the extension is not activated at all. What is wrong in the pom.xml?